# How do I give friendly column names to json in angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

How do I use verbose field names rather than the field names used in json in my ng-grid?  I have small names to reduce json but I want to use the friendly names when displaying them.

```
$scope.data = [{id: 1,
nm: John Doe}
,
{id: 2,
nm: Jane Doe}]
```

desired result:

```
Id              Name
--------------  -------------------------------
1               John Doe
2               Jane Doe
```

Angular code:

```
                $scope.gridOptions = {
                    data: 'data',
                    selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
                    multiSelect: false
                };
```

Comment: Don't. There are much more efficient methods for speeding up JSON responses (caching, lazy loading, speeding up your server). This strategy only makes your life harder.

Comment: But there is only one header section.  I thought I could just change that one time and forget about it.  Plus I have to use very small names for json to conserve space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use column definitions in your gridOptions:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'data',
                columnDefs: [
                   {field: 'id', displayName: 'Id', width: '**'},
                   {field: 'nm', displayName: 'Name', width: '****'}],
                selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
                multiSelect: false
            };
```

Comment: What are the * astericks used for?   Number of spaces?

Comment: Sort of number of spaces -- ng-grid will add up the total asterisks and set the original width proportionally

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly define the columns with their headings if you insist on using small fieldnames.

```
$scope.model.gridOptions = {
 columnDefs: [{ field: 'nm', displayName: 'Full Name' }]
}
```

Comment: When I get a score of 15 I'll hit the up arrow on both of you. thx.